# How to halt a chrome-extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Is there a way to programmatically pause my Chrome extension from all of it's activity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you'll need to handle this yourself.  For example, the popular AdBlock extension sets a flag in localStorage called "adblock_is_paused" when you pause the extension from its popup.  The relevant scripts check for this flag before doing any work.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need the browser to remember the pause status each time it opens, then you can do it entirely in JS. Just wrap all your code inside one function which is called when you want to unpause it.

If the user is pausing it from a popup, and the browser needs to keep track of pause state even when it is closed and reopened, then you can set a variable in localstorage in addition to doing the above. Here's This guide helped me. http://julip.co/2010/01/how-to-build-a-chrome-extension-part-2-options-and-localstorage/

If the user will be pausing it from a content script, then you can do all of the above and then communicate with localstorage (bg page) from the content script via message passing. This should help you get started. http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/messaging.html